# Getting error while creating a record

Tags: trigger, triggercontext, trigggers

I am Getting Error while Creating a record :
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger ManufacturerFieldUpdation caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ManufacturerFieldUpdation: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times): Trigger.ManufacturerFieldUpdation: line 7, column 1

```
if(Trigger.isBefore){
List<SupplierContacts__c> vSc= new List<SupplierContacts__c>();
for(MCAR_Manufacturer__c mfr: trigger.new) {

    **vSc = [select id,Enterprise_ID__c,Supplier_Manager__c,Email__c from 
                  SupplierContacts__c where EnterId__c =:mfr.Enterprise_ID__c ];** 
    System.debug('Supplier Caontact Details are------>'+vSc); 
    System.debug('vsc size is---->'+vSc.Size());
    if(vSc.size()>0) {
       mfr.Supplier_Manager__c  = vSc[0].Supplier_Manager__c;
       mfr.Email__c=vSc[0].Email__c;
    }
}
```

Please guide me in this case, I Marked the line where i am getting error

Comment: First you are querying in for loop which is wrong . Second in your query more records are coming try to put some filter or limit. try this it will solve the problem.

Comment: Chetan, Try to make your query more selective. Refer the below doc: It'll be helpful https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

Answer (score 0):

A good answer for GlynA from discussion boards is that

"Yes, that means it's taking too long.  A couple ways to get more CPU time are to put the code in an @future method (you get 60 seconds of CPU instead of just 10 seconds), or implement it as a Batch Apex job.  Since both of these methods are asynchronous, the trigger and associated DML will complete before the calls to the AccountServices methods are made - but they will be called eventually. "

is that a feasible?

HTH
Prabhan

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are try to query too many records in single SOQL.
There is clear description in error message:

> 1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null)
> 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times)

Consider what may happens if Enterprise_ID__c is null, and there are huge amount (more than 10000 records) of SupplierContacts__c  with empty EnterId__c field, or just a lot of them with some concrete value - it would fail.

You can try to filter data set that you are trying to query by some clauses, or probably put a limit statement in your SOQL.

Also, every time for every record you are performing soql - that also bad practise - in case if you try to update more than 150 record of MCAR_Manufacturer__c object - it will fail.
Useful links about limits and trigger bulkifying:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm

http://www.sfdc99.com/2014/01/18/bulkifying-code/
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code